# PHP Google API: How do I get clearer debugging information?

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm using Google API OAuth2 to authentificate my users (and I'm requesting a few scopes such as calendar).
This part is working but when I'm trying to access the calendar, I'm getting the following error output:

> An error occured while fetching events: { "error": { "errors": [ {
>   "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid
>   Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" }
>   ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } }

Is there some way to get (extra) debugging info on the server or on google api side ?

Comment: Did you enable the google calendar api from the google developer dashboard?

Comment: @jdubu423 Yes, calendar api is enabled...

Comment: what is your authorization http header set to?